# Failed to open native connection to Cassandra from jar produced by intellij

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, cassandra

I've developed a spark-based application that gets data from kafka and saves it in cassandra DB, using intellij.

connection code in scala:

```
val cluster = Cluster.builder().addContactPoint("192.168.0.253").withPort(9042).build();
val session = cluster.connect()
```

the code work fine when I run it from intellij, but I get this error when I try to run it from jar using command line:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: 
Failed to open native connection to Cassandra at {192.168.0.253}:9042 at .... ....
Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException:

All host(s) tried for query failed 
(tried: /192.168.0.253:9042 (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.TransportException: 
[/192.168.0.253] Error writing)) at 

com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection.reconnectInternal(
ControlConnection.java:233) at
com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection.connect(ControlConnection.java:79) 
at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster$Manager.init(Cluster.java:1424) 
at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.getMetadata(Cluster.java:403) 
at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$.
com$datastax$spark$connector$cql$CassandraConnector$$createSession(
CassandraConnector.scala:155) ... 13 more
```

I've produced a jar file from intellij, and I built the jar with dependencies, using [ copy to the output directory and link via manifist ] option.

cassandra.yaml file:

```
#Whether to start the native transport server. 
start_native_transport: true
#port for the CQL native transport to listen for clients on
native_transport_port: 9042
```

Why is this error raised & and how can I fix it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you supply more information? I built a jar too and everything worked fine

Comment: do you run the jar from the same machine which has the intellij ?

Comment: yes I run the jar on the same machine, I did it before and every thing fine, but when I tried to change the jdk version that what happen :/ [spark 1.6, JDK 7], what kind of information do you want?

Comment: What jdk did you change from?

Comment: form java-8-openjdk-amd64 to java-7-openjdk-amd64

Comment: Why did you that?

Comment: the problem was in openjdk and cassandra server, the problem has solved after I used oracleJdk8 & restarted cassandra server.